# Group by date in column which stores timestamp in long(bigint)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I want to fetch count from table per day but the time column is in long so I can not just simply group by time column. I have to group by date in time column. How can I do this?

Table:

```
Column   |  type
----------------
id       |  Long (bigint)
name     |  String (varchar)
time     |  Long  (bigint)
```

I have try following query but it doesn't work as I have time in long and I want to group by date.

```
select time,count(*) from my_table mt group by time;
```

How can I group by date in above query?

One more thing I'm going to use this query in hibernate so need a query that can also be written in hql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we will convert our timestamp to date and then group by date!

```
select mt.time,count(*) from my_table mt group by DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( mt.time ));
```

hoping this will work. cheer :)

Comment: You need back ticks instead of single quotes (or no ticks at all).

Comment: do you know how to do same thing in postgresql?

Comment: @Harry please use "::date" except from_unixtime and date function, So it will become just like (mt.time::date) P.S: sorry currently I have not installed postgresql please verify once and let me know in case of any consern:)

Comment: @Arians:  I tried this: `select time::date from my_table;` and it returns `ERROR:  cannot cast type bigint to date`

Comment: @Harry: please would you specify which version you are using ?

Comment: @happy please try this "datetime::date"

Comment: @Arians I'm using postgres 8.3. What to give as `datetime` in `datetime::date`?

Comment: @harry: [link](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-convert-postgres-timestamp-to-date-yyyy-mm-dd-td1897515.html) please visit once and this [link](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2005-01/msg00156.php) is also more sumerized

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`)) AS date_from_time, COUNT(1)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date_from_time
```

Comment: Its not working. I'm getting result as `null | 588`. 588 is total row count of table.